# Update Dropdownlist on listview update using update panel asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, sqldatasource

I want to re-populate data of a dropdownlist using sql data source when i insert or update data using the Listview control. Is there a way that i can do this without having to refresh my page manually?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="type" DataValueField="type" Width="66px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" OnInserted="SqlDataSource1_Inserted" ID="SqlDataSource1" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [permit] ([type]) VALUES (@type, @description, @Priceday, @Priceweek, @Pricemonth, @Pricesem, @Priceyear)" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [permit]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [permit] WHERE [pid] = @pid" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [permit] SET [type] = @type, [description] = @description, [Priceday] = @Priceday, [Priceweek] = @Priceweek, [Pricemonth] = @Pricemonth, [Pricesem] = @Pricesem, [Priceyear] = @Priceyear WHERE [pid] = @pid">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="pid" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="pid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <span style="">pid:
                <asp:Label ID="pidLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pid") %>' />
                <br />
                type:
                <asp:Label ID="typeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("type") %>' />
                <br />
                description:
                <asp:Label ID="descriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceday:
                <asp:Label ID="PricedayLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Priceday") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceweek:
                <asp:Label ID="PriceweekLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Priceweek") %>' />
                <br />
                Pricemonth:
                <asp:Label ID="PricemonthLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pricemonth") %>' />
                <br />
                Pricesem:
                <asp:Label ID="PricesemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pricesem") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceyear:
                <asp:Label ID="PriceyearLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Priceyear") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                <br />
                <br />
                </span>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <span style="">pid:
                <asp:Label ID="pidLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pid") %>' />
                <br />
                type:
                <asp:TextBox ID="typeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("type") %>' />
                <br />
                description:
                <asp:TextBox ID="descriptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("description") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceday:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PricedayTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Priceday") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceweek:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PriceweekTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Priceweek") %>' />
                <br />
                Pricemonth:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PricemonthTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Pricemonth") %>' />
                <br />
                Pricesem:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PricesemTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Pricesem") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceyear:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PriceyearTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Priceyear") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                <br />
                <br />
                </span>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <span>No data was returned.</span>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                <span style="">type:
                <asp:TextBox ID="typeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("type") %>' />
                <br />
                description:
                <asp:TextBox ID="descriptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("description") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceday:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PricedayTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Priceday") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceweek:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PriceweekTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Priceweek") %>' />
                <br />
                Pricemonth:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PricemonthTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Pricemonth") %>' />
                <br />
                Pricesem:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PricesemTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Pricesem") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceyear:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PriceyearTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Priceyear") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                <br />
                <br />
                </span>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="InsertButton" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span style="">pid:
                <asp:Label ID="pidLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pid") %>' />
                <br />
                type:
                <asp:Label ID="typeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("type") %>' />
                <br />
                description:
                <asp:Label ID="descriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceday:
                <asp:Label ID="PricedayLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Priceday") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceweek:
                <asp:Label ID="PriceweekLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Priceweek") %>' />
                <br />
                Pricemonth:
                <asp:Label ID="PricemonthLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pricemonth") %>' />
                <br />
                Pricesem:
                <asp:Label ID="PricesemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pricesem") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceyear:
                <asp:Label ID="PriceyearLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Priceyear") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                <br />
                <br />
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                    <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                </div>
                <div style="">
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <span style="">pid:
                <asp:Label ID="pidLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pid") %>' />
                <br />
                type:
                <asp:Label ID="typeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("type") %>' />
                <br />
                description:
                <asp:Label ID="descriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceday:
                <asp:Label ID="PricedayLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Priceday") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceweek:
                <asp:Label ID="PriceweekLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Priceweek") %>' />
                <br />
                Pricemonth:
                <asp:Label ID="PricemonthLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pricemonth") %>' />
                <br />
                Pricesem:
                <asp:Label ID="PricesemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pricesem") %>' />
                <br />
                Priceyear:
                <asp:Label ID="PriceyearLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Priceyear") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                <br />
                <br />
                </span>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [permit] WHERE [pid] = @original_pid AND [type] = @original_type AND [description] = @original_description AND [Priceday] = @original_Priceday AND [Priceweek] = @original_Priceweek AND [Pricemonth] = @original_Pricemonth AND [Pricesem] = @original_Pricesem AND [Priceyear] = @original_Priceyear" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [permit] ([type], [description], [Priceday], [Priceweek], [Pricemonth], [Pricesem], [Priceyear]) VALUES (@type, @description, @Priceday, @Priceweek, @Pricemonth, @Pricesem, @Priceyear)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [permit] WHERE ([type] = @type)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [permit] SET [type] = @type, [description] = @description, [Priceday] = @Priceday, [Priceweek] = @Priceweek, [Pricemonth] = @Pricemonth, [Pricesem] = @Pricesem, [Priceyear] = @Priceyear WHERE [pid] = @original_pid AND [type] = @original_type AND [description] = @original_description AND [Priceday] = @original_Priceday AND [Priceweek] = @original_Priceweek AND [Pricemonth] = @original_Pricemonth AND [Pricesem] = @original_Pricesem AND [Priceyear] = @original_Priceyear">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_pid" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_type" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_description" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Priceday" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Priceweek" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Pricemonth" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Pricesem" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Priceyear" Type="Decimal" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="description" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Priceday" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Priceweek" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Pricemonth" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Pricesem" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Priceyear" Type="Decimal" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="type" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="description" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Priceday" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Priceweek" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Pricemonth" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Pricesem" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Priceyear" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_pid" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_type" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_description" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Priceday" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Priceweek" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Pricemonth" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Pricesem" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Priceyear" Type="Decimal" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ListView1" />
```

---

Code-Behind

```
public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
```

{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
}
protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

    //DropDownList1.Items.Dispose();

    DropDownList1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "type";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "type";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your ContentTemplate, try adding:

```
<Triggers>
<asp:AsynchronousPostBack ControlID="ListView1" />
</Triggers>
```

EDIT:

You can try adding to your ListView

```
OnItemInserted="ListView1_OnItemInserted"
```

Then in the codebehind method:

```
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: My sqldatsource one doesn't have insert parameteres so i could only do oninserted and followed what you did there but didn't work still. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your Insert is working? Does your insert show up after you manually refresh the page?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this on your SqlDataSource1_OnItemInserted event:

```
// will delete all of its items
DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

// will release all resourses used by those items
DropDownList1.Items.Dispose();

// this will reload the items on your ddl
DropDownList1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "type";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "type";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: The DropDownList1.Items.Dispose() doesn't work i get an error. Also it won't update the dropdown using the code. I also can't use qlDataSource1_OnItemInserted event i can only use  OnInserted="SqlDataSource1_Inserted".